# How to rollback last executed sql script fired as sysdba

Tags: oracle

I have fired one sql script as **sysdba** which I have to fire using other oracle user.

I have already created some user and each application running on each oracle user. By mistake I had fired a script using one particular user but I have fired it using sysdba.

- How to find .dbf file of sysdba user.
- Can I revert my changes.
- Does it affect other application.
- I have list of tables and sequences. Can I drop individual table and sequence?
- Do you have any better solution.

That script created lots of tables and sequences and inserted data into some tables.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

1. The default tablespace of the SYS (sysdba) user is typically SYSTEM. From that you can figure out the .dbf file being used, although I'm not sure how this will help.
2. Maybe. Does your database run using flashback? Also, manually backing out changes (or write a script to undo what you did) might be possible.
3. Maybe.  What changed?
4. Yes.
5. Be more careful.  Ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com.

EDIT:

I would add that running scripts as the SYSDBA user should be VERY carefully evaluated as to necessity, and probably never used for application purposes.  As you can see, the SYSDBA user has essentially unlimited power over your database.

Comment: I know that table and sequences are created and that can't be revert back but I have the list of all tables and sequences. So, I'm going to delete each of them. That is the right approach I guess?

Comment: Be very sure that the objects that you are planning on deleting were actually created by the script. If you tried to created a table called SEQ$ then it would have failed, because one already exists under the SYS schema. You would definitely not want to drop it. Check using the DBA_OBJECTS view, and look at the CREATED column to check. On a cheery note, I've worked at some places where a mistake like this would have got you fired.

Comment: It is Live Server and now I want to rollback that all at any cost.
But,
Is there any effect if I am not rollback them as each application is working fine. So please suggest the way to get out of this.

Comment: As I said, you *might* be able to undo your changes with flashback, although since you used SYSDBA to do it, this could be problematic. Other than that, I see no other option.  I seriously doubt that a database restore is what you're looking for.  Amen to David Aldridge's comment about possibly getting fired for a mistake like this.  I would add that perhaps the DBA should be fired for giving you access to this account :-)

Comment: I have scrolled all the tables list of sysdba, they all contains atleast one _ OR $ symbol and My tables list doesn't contains that character. I have already made a revert script and Now I'm going to do it. Amen!!!!

Comment: @user3154598 - Second David's comment about being extremely careful about what you drop or change when trying to undo this; you don't want to [end up in this situation by dropping something crucial](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/46830/847), and pretty much everything owned by `SYS` is crucial. If you are not the DBA I suggest you get advice and sign-off from them before doing anything else.

Comment: @AlexPoole Rather, if you are not a/the DBA, get one and never run a script as a DBA again.